# How to handle data of console developer tool for Chrome for automation

Tags: selenium, automation, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I need to automate where We are sending data which is available on console in real time. Automation test can be to check that data is triggering or data format is correct which is being sent. I can manually check this on console but there are lots of things to check and need to automate the process. Is there any method in selenium which we can utilize to interact with console data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`driver.manage().logs().get`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/logging.html). You also need to configure the [`loggingPreferences`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196788/webdriverjs-driver-manage-logs-getbrowser-returns-empty-array) to log normal `console.log` calls, rather than just more severe error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a complete example of using selenium (Python) to write to the console logs and to read from them:

```py
"""Record console logs to: "console.logs"."""
driver.execute_script(
    """
    console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
    console.logs = [];
    console.log = function(){
        console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
        console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    """
)

"""Log a string to the Console (after running the top script)"""
driver.execute_script("""console.log(`%s`);""" % string)

"""Log output of JavaScript to the Console (after running the top script)"""
driver.execute_script("""console.log(%s);""" % script)

"""Get console logs that were recorded above into "console.logs"."""
driver.execute_script("return console.logs;")
```

Reference 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19846113/7058266

Reference 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196986/7058266