# grabbing console log output for a chrome browser using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Title sums it up really. I'm completely new to using selenium with python. Using a python script, I'm trying to run a command on a website's console, then I'm trying to retrieve the output from that command to be used by my python script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromedriver = "path to driver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver)

# load some site
driver.get('http://example.com') #orignally I used foo.com but stackoverflow doesn't like that

driver.execute_script("console.log('hello world')")
# print messages
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
```

but this doesn't return anything

Upon performing an inspect element on the page opened and going to the console. I saw that my hello world message was indeed there.

[image]

But I have no idea why this isn't being returned by my code. Any help would be super appreciated, thankyou!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium Python API bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907180/getting-console-log-output-from-chrome-with-selenium-python-api-bindings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to save the console logs and print them out:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.execute_script("""
    console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console);
    console.logs = [];
    console.log = function(){
        console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
        console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments);
    }
    """)

driver.execute_script("console.log('hello world ABC')")
driver.execute_script("console.log('hello world 123')")

print(driver.execute_script("return console.logs"))

driver.quit()
```

Here's the output of that:

```py
[['hello world ABC'], ['hello world 123']]
```